# How can I set class name dynamically?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I have understood from my last question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30600115/polymer-1-0-issue-with-displaying-values-inside-template-is-dom-repeat) that string concatenate is not allowed with 0.9 and above (currently I am migrating to version 1.0).

I have to rather wrap every variable inside separate HTML element.

However there are times when I need to use a `href` or `class` attribute to be assigned with values dynamically. I cannot make it to work directly like the following:

```
<a href="http://example.com/user/{{userid}}">Link text</a>
```

since 1.0 won't allow string concatenation!

Please see the snippets below. I am trying to pass an attribute value from my `index.html` which in turn should replace the value in `class` attribute inside my custom element. But it is not working and I understand why.

```html
<dom-module id="multi-color-bar-chart">
  <template>
    <div id="chart">
          <p>{{title}}</p>
          <div class="{{v1bg}}">
              <!-- I want {{v1bg}} to be replaced by value sent from index.html -->
              <span>{{value1}}</span>%
          </div>
          <div class="v2" style="background:#ffcc00;">
              <span>{{value2}}</span>%
          </div>
          <div class="v3" style="background:#369925;">
              <span>{{value3}}</span>%
          </div>
          <div class="clear"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="clear"></div>
  </template>
  <script>
      (function () {
          Polymer({
              is: 'multi-color-bar-chart', //registration of element
              properties: {
                  title: { type: String },
                  value1: { type: String },
                  value2: { type: String },
                  value3: { type: String },
                  v1bg: { type: String }
              }
          });
      })();
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Here is the snippet in index.html

```html
<multi-color-bar-chart
  title="Annual"
  value1="45.5"
  value2="22.3"
  value3="32.2"
  v1bg="#ff0000">
  ...
  ...
</multi-color-bar-chart>
```

I am passing a hex code `#ff0000` via `v1bg` attribute which I intend to actually replace the property inside the element.

I don't know yet if there is a work around to it. Might have used `document.querySelector()` but didn't try that yet. If there is a direct HTML approach that would be wonderful.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try `class$="{{v1bg}}"`, as this will bind to the `class` attribute rather than the `class` property.

https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#attribute-binding

Comment: Just noticed href$ does not work like class$. I tried <a href$="http://example.com/{{value}}">...</a> but it is not working. Sorry for back to back questions. A complete newbie to Polymer :)

Comment: `href$="{{value}}"` should work, but as you stated before string concatenation does not work so you wouldn't be able to do `href$="http://example.com/{{value}}"`.  You can do something similar, though: https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties.html#computed-properties

Comment: String concatenation does work in Polymer 1.2, you should upgrade. See: https://blog.polymer-project.org/releases/2015/11/02/release-1.2.0/